# Acces denied error in crawl log when crawling https

Tags: search, crawling, https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access denied error in crawl log](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18913/access-denied-error-in-crawl-log)

When I crawl a https web application I get the following error:

*"https://sitename.domain.nl

Access is denied. Verify that either the Default Content Access Account has access to this repository, or add a crawl rule to crawl this repository. If the repository being crawled is a SharePoint repository, verify that the account you are using has "Full Read" permissions on the SharePoint Web Application being crawled."*

The Default content access account has acces to all web applications. It has full read acces in the user policy of each web application.

When I check the "Ignore SSL warnings" option, the error still occurs.

The disableloopbackcheck option is irrelevant because we are using Windows Server 2008 R2, also I already tried it and it did not resolve the issue ([KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861)).

I am stumped, all comments are welcome.

Comment: you have asked this question on Sept 7. Please just comment or modify the original post rather than creating a new question that is near identical (and answering both).

Answer (score 0):

Oke, it turns out this being caused by our ISA server. We use the ISA server for load balancing and fail-over. This is something that SharePoint does not compute! When I turned the indexing server into a new WFE and added all applications to the host file pointing to the localhost, all the error messages disappeard!

I searched the internet for ages looking for an answer, i hope this one can spare someone from that experience.